# Can a metal which contains impurity of another metal that is more reactive than itself be electrorefined?

Tags: metallurgy

So I know that cathode is made of pure metal and anode of impure. For example take Cu. Cu will be oxidised to Cu+2 at anode and will deposit at cathode.
But now if it contains impurity of , let's say, Zn (even if that doesn't occur in nature just consider hypothetically) then won't Zn be oxidised at anode instead of Cu? Will electrorefining work in such a case?

Comment: Yes it will work. Everything will dissolve, then Cu will reduce.

Comment: "Electrorefining of copper was first demonstrated experimentally by Maximilian, Duke of Leuchtenberg in 1847." (en:wp)

Answer (score 1):

The key point to remember here is that any metal that is oxidized more readily than copper will be reduced less readily. So yes, it will be oxidized before the copper in the impure sample, but it will not be reduced and deposited on the pure metal electrode. It will simply stay in solution as an ion as long as the process is stopped before all of the copper has deposited.